# Communication frequency vs Simulation Time for FMU

Tags: openmodelica, fmi, pyfmi

Lets say we have a FMU which is getting inputs from Python and simulating at an interval of 0.001s. Does the FMI/FMU standard allow us to run the FMU multiple times for a same input (so Python provides the input at 0.01s interval and the FMU simulates that 10 times at each step)? Would that be faster since we have reduced the communication interface by 1/10th ?

Comment: Are you talking about model exchange or co-simulation FMUs?

Comment: Hi I am talking about Model exchange FMUs

Answer (score 0):

(For CS FMUs:) Updating the inputs only every 10th step can be seen as a special co-simualtion algorithm and is ok. Input variables keep their values until they they are newly set.
This will only lead to a benefit in simulation speed, if the the internal calculation time (of a doStep) is small compared to the communication runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would this hold true for Model Exchange FMU ? I am asking because I have a FMU that runs only if it simulates at 0.0001s (fails if it is larger). I am wondering if there is a way to call doStep multiple times but change the inputs at 0.001s interval and whether it will give noticeable performance.